# Oracle Apex page based on loading data after entering the one or its refreshing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Good evening!

At this moment I'm working on page in the Oracle Apex Application, which works the following way. This is the page, which contains some kind of big and complex report with data differentiated by one feature (let it be named *feature A*). On the left side of the page there is a "catalog menu", due to which user can see the data answering to *feature A*, on the right side the data is shown and above there is a the search bar, which can help users to find some exact data by other features *feature B*, *feature C* etc.

I had a view (let it be named *V_REPORT_BIG_DATA*) for showing the report, but it **was so big** and **was loading so slow**, that I've decided to switch the page on the table with the same fields as *V_REPORT_BIG_DATA* (let it be named *T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP*). Besides, it has the additional field for process identificator (let it be named *PID*) and is temporary not physically, but by its purpose. I thought that it must work this way: user enters the page, receives his own *PID* relevant to the session (it works if *PID* is null, otherwise it doesn't change), and then the procedure (*P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD*) makes the deleting of the "old" data and uploading of the "new" one, besides these actions are executed with the one *PID* and are concerned to definite (say, current) user.

But my idea didn't appear to work correct. The procedure *P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD* itself works fine and is executed from the Process page, and *PID* is a global Application Item (it is generated from a database sequence). But my brain has nearly been blown up when I saw that my table has duplicates of data concerned to one user and one *PID*! By making the table of logs (which has been filled with the facts, how much rows had been deleted and inserted again, in the code of *P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD*) I saw very strange thing: some users "loaded" duplicates as if the uploading procedure had been executed several times simultaneously!

Taking into account all I've said before, I have the following question: what do I do wrong? What should I do, so that I wouldn't have to use the word "distinct" in the query from the table *T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP*?

UPD: Additional facts to my question. Excuse me for my inattention, because I thought that there I cannot edit my first posts. :-/

Well, I'll explain my problem further. :) Firstly, I did all the best for my view *P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD* to expect its loading much faster, but it involves many-many rows. Secondly, the code executed from the Process Page (say, during the loading of my page) is this:

```
begin
  if :PID is null then
    :PID := NEW_PID;
  end if;
  P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD(AUTH => :SUSER, PID => :PID);
end;
```

*NEW_PID* is a function which generates new *PID*, and *P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD* is my procedure which refresh the data depending on user and his PID.

and the code of my procedure is this:

```
procedure P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD
  (AUTH in varchar2, PID in number)
is
  NCOUNT_DELETED number;
  NCOUNT_INSERTED number;
begin
  --first of all I check that both parameters are not null - let me omit this part
  --I find the count of data to be deleted (for debug only)
  select count(*)
    into NCOUNT_DELETED
    from T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP T
   where T.AUTHID = AUTH
     and T.PID = P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD.PID;
  --I delete "old" data
  delete from T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP T
  where T.AUTHID = AUTH
    and T.PID = P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD.PID;
  --I upload "new" one
  insert into T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP
    select V.*, PID from 
     (select S.* from V_REPORT_BIG_DATA S
       where S.AUTHID = AUTH); 
  --I find the count of uploaded data (for debug only)
  NCOUNT_INSERTED := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  --I write the logs (for debug only)
  insert into T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP_LG(AUTHID,PID,INS_CNT,DLD_CNT,WHEN)
  values(AUTH,PID,NCOUNT_INSERTED,NCOUNT_DELETED,sysdate);
end P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD;
```

And one more fact: I tried to turn :*PID* into Page Item, but it cleared after every refresh in spite of that the option *Maintain session state* is *Per session*, so that I couldn't even hope for using the same PID by every definite user in definite session.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've described a problem but no code, no way for us to reproduce the problem, and no debugging information.  That's going to make it very unlikely that someone else will be able to guess what your bug is.  You can enable debugging in APEX, you can print messages before you call your procedure, you can examine session state to figure out what isn't working the way you expect.  Architecturally, though, I'm hard-pressed to guess why it would be more efficient to query the view to put data into a table rather than just querying the view in the application.

Comment: @JustinCave, OK, I'll explain my problem further. :) Firstly, I did all the best for my view _P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD_ to expect its loading much faster, but it involves many-many rows. Secondly, the code executed from the Process Page (say, during the loading of my page) is this:
--
begin
 if :PID is null then :PID := NEW_PID; end if;
 P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD(AUTH => :SUSER, PID => :PID);
end;
--
_NEW_PID_ is a function which generates new PID, and _P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD_ is my procedure which refresh the data depending on user and his PID.

Comment: @JustinCave, and the code of my procedure is this:
--
procedure P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD(AUTH in varchar2, PID in number) is

begin
  --first of all I check that both parameters are not null - let me omit this part
  --I delete "old" data
  delete from T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP T where T.AUTHID = AUTH and T.PID = P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD.PID;
  --I upload "new" one
  insert into T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP select V.*, PID
  from (select S.* from V_REPORT_BIG_DATA S where S.AUTHID = AUTH);
end P_REPORT_BIG_DATA_RELOAD;

Comment: @JustinCave, moreover, for understanding what I do wrong I added some extra code: I find the count of deleted rows (before the deleting itself I execute the query "select count(*) into :NCOUNT_DELETED from <the data to be deleted>"), then the count of inserted ones (right after the inserting of "new" data I use the variable SQL%ROWCOUNT) and all that information with the name of user, PID and current time I insert into log table T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP_LG.

Comment: @JustinCave, sorry, I forgot one more fact: I tried to turn :PID into Page Item, but it cleared after every refresh in spite of that the option "Maintain session state" is "Per session", so that I couldn't even hope for using the same PID by every definite user in definite session.

Comment: First, please edit your post to include code rather than putting code in comments.  That way, you can format your code so that it is readable and other folks that see your question don't need to wade through comments to understand what you're asking.  Second, I am still hard-pressed to understand how it can be faster to select all the data from a view into a table after deleting the data from a prior run rather than simply selecting that same data set to appear on your page.  In both cases, you appear to be selecting the exact same data set.  You're just doing additional inserts and deletes.

Comment: @JustinCave, I've already added my comments to my main post. And I must admit once more, that I would use the view, but it loads too slow and it was done the best for making it less huge by its time of loading.

Comment: Your `insert` statement is invalid syntax.  It references a `v.*` but there is no alias `v`.  If the subquery `select S.* from V_REPORT_BIG_DATA where S.AUTHID = AUTH` is supposed to be aliased `v` then I'm confused at why you'd select the `pid` again since it would only be valid if the `v` subquery was already returning it.  If querying the view is slow, querying the view must be slow whether it is being done in the application or in the procedure.

Comment: If querying the view is only slow if done from the application than the query you're running from the application is slow and you should debug that problem rather than materializing the data into a non-temporary table that is named `_TEMP`.  If querying the view in the application is the same speed as querying the view from the procedure then the procedure will be slower overall because it's doing additional work to delete and insert data in a permanent table.

Comment: @JustinCave, I'm so sorry for that I forgot to type the letter "V". Of course, it should be there. But the view doesn't have _PID_ - this column is present on in the table _T_REPORT_BIG_DATA_TEMP_. And when I told about my view, I'd meant that its querying is slow itself, not only in application. And when I've already entered the page, going on every "catalog" is happening very fast, when I use the table.